# Using mvn install-file - getting classdefnotfound for the installed projects dependancy

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

Deploying to Elastic Beanstalk via AWS CodeBuild.
Prior to building my project within AWS, I am running

`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=lib/my-lib.jar -Dcom.me -DartifactId=my-lib -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar`

to import a personal library that isn't available on a public repo.

Within `my-lib/pom.xml`, I import a number of number of dependancies that all happen to be shared with the main project, but the 1 that isn't results in a `classdefnotfound` exception at runtime when imported. If I add this dependancy to the main project, it works fine.

Why is this dependency not being resolved when it is installed prior to installation of the main project that depends on it?

Should dependancies of this nature be within dependency management?